# Visualization of zero values and small values in the same histogram in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

I want to plot a single histogram where some of the x-values are 0, while the other x-values range between 0.002 and 0.008. The problem is that even by specifying the `xlim`, the columns overlap but of course they should not.

```
x1 = zeros (3000,1);
hist(x1);xlim([0 0.008]);
h = findobj(gca,'Type','patch');
set(h,'Facecolor',[1 0 0]);
set(h,'FaceAlpha',0.7);
hold on
n = 3000;
R = [0.002 0.008];
x2 = rand(n,1)*range(R)+min(R);
hist(x2);xlim([0 1])
h1 = findobj(gca,'Type','patch');
set(h1,'facealpha',.3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to use two histograms?

```
hist([x1; x2])
```

[image]